# Not sure what to do about this: undefined reference to `__imp_CM_Get_DevNode_Status' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, winapi

To make a long story short my Bluetooth drivers bug out sometimes, and I've been working on a program that will detect this and restart the device. Today I've tried to work on a better way to do such. My source code isn't marked as having any errors, but if I try to compile it I get this mess spat out at me.

C:\Users\[MYNAME]\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9pE701.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x520): undefined reference to `__imp_CM_Get_DevNode_Status'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And I've checked around the internet, but I have yet to find someone with this *exact* problem I've seen some similar ones though none of them seem to have a solution. I'm seriously lost at this point any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm certain that it's to do with the call to `CM_Get_DevNode_Status();` but I don't know how to fix this. I have the windows SDK installed, cfgmgr32.dll is working fine, and included cfgmgr32.h in the file. Which unfortunately covers all the things *I* thought it might be.

Comment: Are you linking with either `Cfgmgr32.lib` or `OneCoreUAP.lib` on Windows 10? - see __Requirements__ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_devnode_status

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?: Failure to link against appropriate libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400)

Comment: @RichardCritten That Might be it I'll look into it and see what I can figure out.